# How can I run two diffrent Python programs to control one common Queue?

Tags: python, queue

Here are the sources:

```
#one.py: 
from Queue import Queue 
req = Queue()
```

---

```
#two.py: 
import one 
import time 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    while True: 
    print "this is two.py and reqID is ",id(one.req) 
    print "Queue size is %s"%one.req.qsize() 
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

```
#three.py: 
import one 
import time 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    while True: 
    print "this is three.py and reqID is ",id(one.req) 
    print "Queue size is %s"%one.req.qsize() 
    one.req.put(2) 
    time.sleep(5)
```

`one.py` has a common Queue. I want to use `two.py` and `three.py` to control `one.py`'s common queue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are a few options that come to mind:

- You could use an operating system pipe (FIFO, whatever), and read/write data from/to it like a file.  This wouldn't use the `Queue` system at all.
- You could combine the programs the other way around.  Have two.py and three.py just define their respective functions, then `import two, three` from one.py, and fork processes from within one.py.  Use `multiprocessing` for this probably.  I'm not 100% sure if the `Queue` will work properly with fully forked processes.  The `multiprocessing` package also has its own `Queue` class.
- Just use python threads.  I get the impression that this isn't suitable for your application, but thought I'd put it here anyway.

The second option is probably what I would do.  The functions in two.py and three.py would need to take a `Queue` as an argument.

Comment: thank you very much .I find a method,that is celery and rabbitmq,but I don't try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Two different programs cannot directly access each other's data. This is called process isolation in operating systems context:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation

You need to use interprocess communication for that. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Example of IPC features in python standard library:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html